# Underline issue with form

Tags: html, css

The issue I am having is trying to get the red underline under all of my inputs. Right now it is only doing half of them even though they are all inputs. It appears that it is only giving my first section underlines... Can someone see why my first section is the only one with underlines and my section section isn't? Thank you for your help!

here is a jsfiddle to see it:
https://jsfiddle.net/acr3jw29/

html:

```
<body>

<h1>Contact</h1>

<form action="" methods="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on" class="contact">
<section class="clearfix">
<fieldset><legend><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Personal Information

```
<label><span>First Name</span> <input name="first_name" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name Here" autofocus required/>
</label>
<label><span>Last Name</span><input name="last_name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name Here" autofocus required/>
</label>
<label><span>Date of Birth</span> <input name="date_of_birth" type="date" value="" placeholder="Date of Birth" autofocus required/>
</label>


<label><span>Level of Education</span> <input name="level_of_education" type="" value="" placeholder="" autofocus required/></label>
<select name="education_level">
<option value="High School">High School</option>
<option value="Undergraduate">Undergradute</option>
<option value="Graduate">Graduate</option>
</select>





<label><span>Number of years until next degree is completed </span>       
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="6" autofocus></label>

</fieldset>




<fieldset><legend><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Contact Information

```
<label><span>Email</span><input class="ghost-input" name="email" value="" type="email" placeholder="youremail@email.com" autocomplete="off" /></label>

<label><span>Phone Number</span><input name="phonenumber" value="" type="tel" placeholder="743-558-2196" /></label>

<label><span>Website</span><input name="website" value="" type="url" placeholder="https://yoururl.com"/></label>



</fieldset>




</section>




<section class="clearfix column"  >


<fieldset><legend><i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

What are your Interests

```
<label><span>Web Design</span><input name="webdesign" value="web_design" type="checkbox"/></label>

<label><span>Web Development</span><input name="webdevelopment" value="web_development" type="checkbox" /></label>

<label><span>Computer Science</span><input name="computerscience" value="computer_science" type="checkbox" /></label>




<label><span>Graphic Design</span><input name="graphicdesign" value="graphic_design" type="checkbox" /></label>

<label><span>User Experience</span><input name="userexperience" value="user_experience" type="checkbox" /></label>

<label><span>App Development</span><input name="appdevelopment" value="app_development" type="checkbox" /></label>


</fieldset>



<fieldset><legend><i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone" aria-hidden="true">

</i>

Continuation</legend>



<legend>You can contact me by:</legend>
<br>
<label><span>Contact me by phone</span><input  name="contact_me" type="radio" value="phone" checked/></label>
<label><span>Contact me by email</span><input  name="contact_me" type="radio" value="email"/></label>
<label><span>Contact me by text</span><input  name="contact_me" type="radio" value="text"/></label>
<br>


<legend>I'm interested in:</legend>
<br>

<label><span>Undergraduate</span><input name="interest" type="radio" value="text"/></label>
<label><span>Graduate</span><input  name="interest" type="radio" value="text"/></label>
<label><span>Online</span><input  name="interest" type="radio" value="text"/></label>

</fieldset>



</section>






</form>
<br>
<input name="submit_to_programmer" type="submit" value="Submit"/>


<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8f5d316ef9.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: oh weird.. I'll have to look into it thank you

Comment: same issue here with firefox 45.3.0..no border applying for checkbox and radio

Comment: Also on Chromium Version 52.0.2743.116 Built on 8.5, running on Debian Kali Linux 2.0 (64-bit) same issue

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, I misunderstood and now realize that you also want the check boxes underlined, You're right, `input` seems to only apply to text inputs

Answer (score 1):

For proper display in all browser, a quick fix would be to place all input container of checkbox and radio type inside a span. I noticed you have set `display:block;` for all span elements in your codes. So I inserted a class for each span container that will be holding the  input boxes and style with an inline-block display.

see snippet below

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

form.contact label {
  display: block;
}

span {
  display: block;
  border: none;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

section {
  width: 90%;
}

fieldset {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  border: none;
}

input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  margin: 3px;
}
.in_container{
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Contact</h1>

  <form action="" methods="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on" class="contact">
    <section class="clearfix">
      <fieldset>
        <legend><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Personal Information</legend>

        <label><span>First Name</span>
          <input name="first_name" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name Here" autofocus required/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Last Name</span>
          <input name="last_name" type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name Here" autofocus required/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Date of Birth</span>
          <input name="date_of_birth" type="date" value="" placeholder="Date of Birth" autofocus required/>
        </label>


        <label><span>Level of Education</span>
          <input name="level_of_education" type="" value="" placeholder="" autofocus required/>
        </label>
        <select name="education_level">
          <option value="High School">High School</option>
          <option value="Undergraduate">Undergradute</option>
          <option value="Graduate">Graduate</option>
        </select>
        <label><span>Number of years until next degree is completed </span>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="6" autofocus>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact Information</legend>

        <label><span>Email</span>
          <input class="ghost-input" name="email" value="" type="email" placeholder="youremail@email.com" autocomplete="off" />
        </label>

        <label><span>Phone Number</span>
          <input name="phonenumber" value="" type="tel" placeholder="743-558-2196" />
        </label>

        <label><span>Website</span>
          <input name="website" value="" type="url" placeholder="https://yoururl.com" />
        </label>
      </fieldset>
    </section>
    <section class="clearfix column">
      <fieldset>
        <legend><i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> What are your Interests</legend>
        <label><span>Web Design</span>
          <span class="in_container">
            <input name="webdesign" value="web_design" type="checkbox" />
          </span>
        </label>

        <label><span>Web Development</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="webdevelopment" value="web_development" type="checkbox" />
          </span>
        </label>

        <label><span>Computer Science</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="computerscience" value="computer_science" type="checkbox" />
          </span>
        </label>
        <label><span>Graphic Design</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="graphicdesign" value="graphic_design" type="checkbox" />
          </span>
        </label>

        <label><span>User Experience</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="userexperience" value="user_experience" type="checkbox" />
          </span>
        </label>

        <label><span>App Development</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="appdevelopment" value="app_development" type="checkbox" />
          </span>
        </label>

      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend><i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone" aria-hidden="true">

</i> Continuation
        </legend>
        <legend>You can contact me by:</legend>
        <br>
        <label><span>Contact me by phone</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="contact_me" type="radio" value="phone" checked/>
          </span>
        </label>
        <label><span>Contact me by email</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="contact_me" type="radio" value="email" />
          </span>
        </label>
        <label><span>Contact me by text</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="contact_me" type="radio" value="text" />
          </span>
        </label>
        <br>
        <legend>I'm interested in:</legend>
        <br>

        <label><span>Undergraduate</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="interest" type="radio" value="text" />
          </span>
        </label>
        <label><span>Graduate</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="interest" type="radio" value="text" />
          </span>
        </label>
        <label><span>Online</span>
          <span class="in_container">
          <input name="interest" type="radio" value="text" />
          </span>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
    </section>
  </form>
  <br>
  <span class="in_container">
  <input name="submit_to_programmer" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </span>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8f5d316ef9.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```